# How can I create/run benchmarks for custom kernels in tensorflow?

Tags: benchmarking, tensorflow

There is already some functionality in tensorflow to create benchmarks which can be seen in action for example [in the adjust contrast op benchmark](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/adjust_contrast_op_benchmark_test.cc). If I run this on my machine, however, I just get an empty output:

```
panmari@dingle:~/tensorflow$ bazel run //tensorflow/core:kernels_adjust_contrast_op_benchmark_test --test_output=all --cache_test_results=no -- --benchmarks=1000
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //tensorflow/core:kernels_adjust_contrast_op_benchmark_test up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/tensorflow/core/kernels_adjust_contrast_op_benchmark_test
INFO: Elapsed time: 10.736s, Critical Path: 8.71s.

INFO: Running command line: bazel-bin/tensorflow/core/kernels_adjust_contrast_op_benchmark_test '--benchmarks=1000'.
Running main() from test_main.cc
Benchmark    Time(ns) Iterations
--------------------------------
```

Is my invocation of wrong?

Comment: Can you try passing the command-line flag `--benchmarks=all` instead of `--benchmarks=1000`?

Comment: @mrry that worked, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To invoke the benchmarks, run the following command (passing `--benchmarks=all` as the final argument):

```
$ bazel run -c opt //tensorflow/core:kernels_adjust_contrast_op_benchmark_test \
      --test_output=all --cache_test_results=no -- --benchmarks=all
```

To run GPU benchmarks, you must pass `--config=cuda` to `bazel` and append `_gpu` to the name of the test target. For example:

```
$ bazel run -c opt --config=cuda \ 
     //tensorflow/core:kernels_adjust_contrast_op_benchmark_test_gpu \
     --test_output=all --cache_test_results=no -- --benchmarks=all
```

Comment: For future reference: This has changed, the build rule now needs a '_gpu' suffix for running gpu benchmarks. See documentation at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD#L12

Comment: When you're at it, you could also add proper optimization flags: --config opt --config=cuda